# CyclicDist goes slower on multiple locales

Tags: performance, parallel-processing, low-latency, chapel, parallelism-amdahl

I tried doing an implementation of Matrix multiplication using **`CyclicDist`** module.

When I test with one locale vs two locales, the one locale is much faster. Is it because the time to communicate between the two Jetson nano boards is really big or is my implementation not taking advantage of the way `CyclicDist` works?

Here is my code:

```
 use Random, Time, CyclicDist;
var t : Timer;
t.start();

config const size = 10;
const Space = {1..size, 1..size};

const gridSpace = Space dmapped Cyclic(startIdx=Space.low);
var grid: [gridSpace] real;
fillRandom(grid);
const gridSpace2 = Space dmapped Cyclic(startIdx=Space.low);
var grid2: [gridSpace2] real;
fillRandom(grid2);
const gridSpace3 = Space dmapped Cyclic(startIdx=Space.low);
var grid3: [gridSpace] real;
forall i in 1..size do {
    forall j in 1..size do {
        forall k in 1..size do {
            grid3[i,j] += grid[i,k] * grid2[k,j];
        }
    }
}
t.stop();
writeln("Done!:");
writeln(t.elapsed(),"seconds");
writeln("Size of matrix was:", size);
t.clear()
```

I know my implementation is not optimal for distributed memory systems.

Comment: working on 551?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the main reason that this program is not scaling is that the computation never uses any locales other than the initial one.  Specifically, forall loops over ranges, like the ones in your code:

```
forall i in 1..size do
```

always run all of their iterations using tasks executing on the current locale.  This is because ranges are not distributed values in Chapel and as a result, their parallel iterators don't distribute work across locales.  As a result of this, all size**3 executions of the loop body:

```
grid3[i,j] += grid[i,k] * grid2[k,j];
```

will run on locale 0 and none of them will run on locale 1.  You can see that this is the case by putting the following into the innermost loop's body:

```
writeln("locale ", here.id, " running ", (i,j,k));
```

(where `here.id` prints out the ID of the locale where the current task is running).  This will show that locale 0 is running all iterations:

```
0 running (9, 1, 1)
0 running (1, 1, 1)
0 running (1, 1, 2)
0 running (9, 1, 2)
0 running (1, 1, 3)
0 running (9, 1, 3)
0 running (1, 1, 4)
0 running (1, 1, 5)
0 running (1, 1, 6)
0 running (1, 1, 7)
0 running (1, 1, 8)
0 running (1, 1, 9)
0 running (6, 1, 1)
...
```

Contrast this with running a forall loop over a distributed domain like `gridSpace`:

```
forall (i,j) in gridSpace do
  writeln("locale ", here.id, " running ", (i,j));
```

where the iterations will be distributed between the locales:

```
locale 0 running (1, 1)
locale 0 running (9, 1)
locale 0 running (1, 2)
locale 0 running (9, 2)
locale 0 running (1, 3)
locale 0 running (9, 3)
locale 0 running (1, 4)
locale 1 running (8, 1)
locale 1 running (10, 1)
locale 1 running (8, 2)
locale 1 running (2, 1)
locale 1 running (8, 3)
locale 1 running (10, 2)
...
```

Since all of the computation is running on locale 0 but half of the data is located on locale 1 (due to the arrays being distributed), lots of communication is generated to fetch remote values from locale 1's memory to locale 0's in order to compute on it.

Comment: Another tip on your code: Since the values and distributions of `gridSpace`, `gridSpace2`, and `gridSpace3` are all identical, you can save time, space, and complexity by just declaring one domain and using it to declare all three arrays.

Answer (score 2):

> **Q** : *Is it because the **time to communicate** <sub>(1)</sub>   **between the two Jetson nano boards** is really big **or** is my **implementation**  <sub>(2)</sub>  **not taking advantage** of the way `CyclicDist` works?*

The second option is a sure bet: **`~ 100 x` worse** performance was achieved on `CyclicDist` data for small sizes.

**Documentation** explicitly [*warns*](https://chapel-lang.org/docs/modules/dists/CyclicDist.html#cyclicdist) on this, saying:

> *Cyclic distribution maps indices to locales in a round-robin pattern starting at a given index.
> ...
> Limitations
>
>   This distribution has not been tuned for performance.*

Adverse impacts on processing efficiency were demonstrable on a single-locale platform, where all data resides in the locale-local memory space, thus without any NUMA inter-board communication add-on costs ever added. Still **`~ 100 x` worse** performance was achieved, compared to [Vass' single-`forall{}`](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/59278506/1) **`D3`**-iterated sum-product

<sub>( not noticed until now Vass' performance motivated change from the original `forall-in-D3-do-{}` into another configured  `forall-in-D2-do-for{}`-tandem-iterated revision - so far, small-size --fast --ccflags -O3 performed test show **almost half the length WORSE** performance for the `forall-in-D2-do-for{}`-iterator-in-iterator results, even worse than the O/P triple-`forall{}` original proposal, except for sizes under 512x512 and after -O3 optimisation took place, but for a smallest size 128x128

The highest performance was achieved of `~ 850 [ns]` per cell for the original Vass-D3 solo-iterator, surprisingly without --ccflags -O3 ( which might be obviously changed for larger `--size={ 1024 | 2048 | 4096 | 8192 }` data-layouts being processed, the more if wider-NUMA multi-locale and higher parallelism devices are being put into the race ) )</sub>

```
TiO.run platform uses   1 numLocales,
               having   2 physical CPU-cores accessible (numPU-s)
                 with   2 maxTaskPar parallelism limit
```

The use of the `CyclicDist` effects the DATA -into- memory layout, doesn't it?

Validated by measurements on **small sizes** [`--size={128 | 256 | 512 | 640}`](https://tio.run/##zVldb5tIFH33r7iqVMneBZv5YGZoNg/RditFWilSm3YfvH5AME5osEGA6@xGyU9f7/Dh1I5tDIGajhRsPDNw5t5zZu5RnFs7lP5qtYglfLTnbjDT4NqbSQ0ur4YfgmhmJ4l0L680@P0fx/ec916cnPW@2REkCN5lQ6PiHn@/7yVoGCd2lPQHZzAa6Q3bGE16PSeYT70bUB9xAkdb7P0r4RwQFme94qfdmZ9C20lHPaDhMJ2gQfHl8cWkm8hz14PzT3dmh6F0i6j0IVvtpXu/HjD0gyUM8shANh@9Gz8/ZgKRtP3NXlzaS/b09qae7@cp62fPV2978RMepKnAm6k4r9DGWIV7GkS274MH3nwdFXjIolL0fN3t2ei9298L6wWNPe3rBH49z0Oj7u4m8EseifGd6npOADz28utjsZQgrL6SbCkZF9ez9Da4uEWiZeQlctqHN0ot2QIekIY18jh@Sz1N/U0guZWQyFjpaB2deDHTwyhwF04CwTcZvaBTwbEkCO7gLcIejBfxRAXU8YewkeKBHoTx3/M3Wu@wBl7TpwImfTuMpdvPBP157iXxcOY5URBLJQg3hsGBqYOzjoIj708VHNwkOKMR6B23HMPUjpPvaNS39OZlktLtU0svDdOUN2yaAokyLjfCcLhtYAAgBje7xoCRJcpoWwHDFzuO09eGinXuazAgi9MyDPCbrqvX8fviqPzz6q8/PsLSS243KoHnnL@/uL44BYMwJdaRyO2FgU2mpZc2YGBEEaW0NomqYqiWQMwNy@waA6EWqU3kbQxNiYwRI@gokcES20RWr57DchTsI7NrJ/YJWIQxRfw1ZDYR1tJLCzAQs4Rgoj6R2sTAKRXY4D8MQyUiYSYQQh1jMA1hsdqC2sbQUFCYWKL8dMoFxdGek2E70ZmoDp4MrTKIWMigVsPINVUSUfkj5ZF7eoInLAu5pTWYem4auWCRqFLMcaa@fRODfkUOaZ9RQ0svLSAmJiKM8Pq6q4qhEt8Iw9go3X@KDZw35Fu7qKkpmFmbb9sYGiqVEH5kt8hrOIOcKHKVOGeYWJQrNVcJkbSySn4eS7UDDw6MP0WxbBCOO7dbSFid2y3FuO7t1jHSZ3aLFVL9cPHpOqtS7Xl9vbZLI8qsozvdCaplRBnq2u@ow5J3jgGTV7C5Zc9lYUZrlIiN2NwqjQxLEEq7Nl1cFV4Cs25NlyEQ5qRrw4O4YB1jIBYxUNemixhVrAOTZKco2i05fjBvsElIt1Yr5S4xcQ2rFfvB8lC8TuCzGGXE6NpnEYN1jYGanOIKjoW26lia@izFd5NUQI1/Kp/FTUrK67bVaqXr6f@6zpUu/8s1scp9zOpZJCslkv8B) with and without a minor `--ccflags -O3` effect

```
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --fast
// ------
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took       255818 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product                           took         3075 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took         3040 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product                           took         2198 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took         1974 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <-- 127x      SLOWER with CyclicDist dmapped DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took         2122 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took       252439 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took      2141444 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product                           took        27095 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took        25339 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product                           took        23493 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took        21631 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <--  98x      SLOWER then w/o CyclicDist dmapped data
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took        21971 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took      2122417 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     16988685 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     17448207 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product                           took       268111 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       270289 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product                           took       250896 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took       239898 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <--  71x      SLOWER with dmapped CyclicDist DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       257479 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     17391049 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     16932503 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <~~ ~2e5 [us] faster without --ccflags -O3
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     35136377 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product                           took       362205 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops <--  97x      SLOWER with dmapped CyclicDist DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       367651 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product                           took       345865 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took       337896 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <-- 103x      SLOWER with dmapped CyclicDist DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       351101 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     35052849 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <~~ ~3e4 [us] faster without --ccflags -O3
//
// --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// --fast --ccflags -O3
// --------------------
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took       250372 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product                           took         3189 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took         2966 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product                           took         2284 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took         1949 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <-- 126x      FASTER than with dmapped CyclicDist DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took         2072 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 128, 128] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took       246965 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took      2114615 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product                           took        37775 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took        38866 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product                           took        32384 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took        29264 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <--  71x      FASTER than with dmapped CyclicDist DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took        33973 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 256, 256] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took      2098344 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     17136826 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     17081273 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product                           took       251786 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       266766 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product                           took       239301 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took       233003 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <~~ ~6e3 [us] faster with --ccflags -O3
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       253642 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     17025339 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 512, 512] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     17081352 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <~~ ~2e5 [us] slower with --ccflags -O3
//
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     35164630 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product                           took       363060 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       489529 [us] incl. fillRandom()-ops
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product                           took       345742 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <-- 104x      SLOWER with dmapped CyclicDist DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the Vass-D3  orig sum-product                           took       353353 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <-- 102x      SLOWER with dmapped CyclicDist DATA
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the Vass-D2-k ver sum-product                           took       471213 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops <~~~12e5 [us] slower with --ccflags -O3
// For grid{1,2,3}[ 640, 640] the tested forall sum-product over dmapped Cyclic Space took     35075435 [us] excl. fillRandom()-ops
```

In any case, the Chapel team's insights (both design-wise and testing-wise) are important. @Brad was asked for a kind help to provide similar testing-coverage and  comparisons for principally higher sizes `--size={1024 | 2048 | 4096 | 8192 | ...}` and for the "way-wider"-NUMA-platforms having multi-locale and many-locale solutions, available at Cray for the Chapel team's R&D, that will not suffer from a hardware and `~ 60 [s]` limits on a public, sponsored, shared [TiO.RUN](https://tio.run/##zVldb5tIFH33r7iqVMneBZv5YGZoNg/RditFWilSm3YfvH5AME5osEGA6@xGyU9f7/Dh1I5tDIGajhRsPDNw5t5zZu5RnFs7lP5qtYglfLTnbjDT4NqbSQ0ur4YfgmhmJ4l0L680@P0fx/ec916cnPW@2REkCN5lQ6PiHn@/7yVoGCd2lPQHZzAa6Q3bGE16PSeYT70bUB9xAkdb7P0r4RwQFme94qfdmZ9C20lHPaDhMJ2gQfHl8cWkm8hz14PzT3dmh6F0i6j0IVvtpXu/HjD0gyUM8shANh@9Gz8/ZgKRtP3NXlzaS/b09qae7@cp62fPV2978RMepKnAm6k4r9DGWIV7GkS274MH3nwdFXjIolL0fN3t2ei9298L6wWNPe3rBH49z0Oj7u4m8EseifGd6npOADz28utjsZQgrL6SbCkZF9ez9Da4uEWiZeQlctqHN0ot2QIekIY18jh@Sz1N/U0guZWQyFjpaB2deDHTwyhwF04CwTcZvaBTwbEkCO7gLcIejBfxRAXU8YewkeKBHoTx3/M3Wu@wBl7TpwImfTuMpdvPBP157iXxcOY5URBLJQg3hsGBqYOzjoIj708VHNwkOKMR6B23HMPUjpPvaNS39OZlktLtU0svDdOUN2yaAokyLjfCcLhtYAAgBje7xoCRJcpoWwHDFzuO09eGinXuazAgi9MyDPCbrqvX8fviqPzz6q8/PsLSS243KoHnnL@/uL44BYMwJdaRyO2FgU2mpZc2YGBEEaW0NomqYqiWQMwNy@waA6EWqU3kbQxNiYwRI@gokcES20RWr57DchTsI7NrJ/YJWIQxRfw1ZDYR1tJLCzAQs4Rgoj6R2sTAKRXY4D8MQyUiYSYQQh1jMA1hsdqC2sbQUFCYWKL8dMoFxdGek2E70ZmoDp4MrTKIWMigVsPINVUSUfkj5ZF7eoInLAu5pTWYem4auWCRqFLMcaa@fRODfkUOaZ9RQ0svLSAmJiKM8Pq6q4qhEt8Iw9go3X@KDZw35Fu7qKkpmFmbb9sYGiqVEH5kt8hrOIOcKHKVOGeYWJQrNVcJkbSySn4eS7UDDw6MP0WxbBCOO7dbSFid2y3FuO7t1jHSZ3aLFVL9cPHpOqtS7Xl9vbZLI8qsozvdCaplRBnq2u@ow5J3jgGTV7C5Zc9lYUZrlIiN2NwqjQxLEEq7Nl1cFV4Cs25NlyEQ5qRrw4O4YB1jIBYxUNemixhVrAOTZKco2i05fjBvsElIt1Yr5S4xcQ2rFfvB8lC8TuCzGGXE6NpnEYN1jYGanOIKjoW26lia@izFd5NUQI1/Kp/FTUrK67bVaqXr6f@6zpUu/8s1scp9zOpZJCslkv8B) platform.